# Excel VBA and Yahoo Finance - Can't quite find the answer I'm looking for

Tags: vba, yahoo-finance

I'm pretty new at VBA and I've looked through a few threads online but haven't quite found anything that works the way I want.

The idea is that the user will paste data onto sheet 1, such as ticker symbol, date, account number, and price paid etc. I would like to create a macro assigned to a button that will auto populate sheet 2 with the following columns:

Symbol(pulled from sheet 1 Column F), TradePrice (pulled from sheet 1 Column N), TradeDate (pulled from sheet 1 column L), Low(pulled from yahoo finance for the given trade date), High(pulled from yahoo finance for the given trade date).

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: This looks like an Excel-related question (since you mention sheets). Add the proper tags. Show us some real data, for instance use a screenshot to show how the sheet looks on screen. Tell us what you attempted so far. What worked and what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

http://ogres-crypt.com/SMF

http://ogres-crypt.com/SMF/Documentation/viewer.php?name=RCHGetYahooQuotes-Function.html

This add-in tool will create several native functions that will allow you to grab the relevant  information. It is too lengthy to post the actual code.